# 409 conflict error only on wifi only during register

Tags: laravel, http-status-code-409

I am trying to register the user. But the registration process is working fine on mobile data but it is returning 409 error on wifi network. I am unknown about this problem. The postman is also returning the 409 conflict.
I am getting this response in android app:

```
E/Volley: [88456] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 409 for https://aayocab.com/api/provider/register/
```

[image]

It was working fine during the initial phase of project.  But it starts returning the conflict now and I am in dilema. I have implemented as follows:

The laravel code to register:

```
  public function register(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
            'device_id' => 'required',
            'device_type' => 'required|in:android,ios',
            'device_token' => 'required',
            'first_name' => 'required|max:255',
            'last_name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:providers',
            'mobile' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    try{
        $Provider = $request->all();
        $Provider['password'] = bcrypt($request->password);
        $providerCode = 'p'.mt_rand(100, 999). mt_rand(100, 999);
        $Provider['provider_code'] = $providerCode;
        $Provider = Provider::create($Provider);

        if(Setting::get('demo_mode', 0) == 1) {
            $Provider->update(['status' => 'approved']);
            ProviderService::create([
                'provider_id' => $Provider->id,
                'service_type_id' => '1',
                'status' => 'active',
                'service_number' => '4pp03ets',
                'service_model' => 'Audi R8',
            ]);
        }
        ProviderDevice::create([
                'provider_id' => $Provider->id,
                'udid' => $request->device_id,
                'token' => $request->device_token,
                'type' => $request->device_type,
            ]);
        return $Provider;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
         return response()->json(['error' => trans('api.something_went_wrong')], 500);
    }     
}
```

I have parsed the data as follows in andorid application:

```
 private void registerAPI() {

    customDialog = new CustomDialog(context);
    customDialog.setCancelable(false);
    if (customDialog != null)
        customDialog.show();
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
    try {
        object.put("device_type", "android");
        object.put("device_id", device_UDID);
        object.put("device_token", device_token);
        object.put("login_by", "manual");
        object.put("first_name", first_name.getText().toString());
        object.put("last_name", last_name.getText().toString());
        object.put("email", email.getText().toString());
        object.put("password", password.getText().toString());
        object.put("password_confirmation", password.getText().toString());
        object.put("mobile", SharedHelper.getKey(RegisterActivity.this, "mobile"));

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, URLHelper.register, object, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            if (customDialog != null && customDialog.isShowing())
                customDialog.dismiss();
            utils.print("SignInResponse", response.toString());

            SharedHelper.putKey(RegisterActivity.this, "email", email.getText().toString());
            SharedHelper.putKey(RegisterActivity.this, "password", password.getText().toString());
            signIn();
        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            if (customDialog != null && customDialog.isShowing())
                customDialog.dismiss();
            String json = null;
            String Message;
            NetworkResponse response = error.networkResponse;
            if (response != null && response.data != null) {
                Log.e("Error SignIN","::"+response.data.toString());
                Log.e("Error SignIN","::"+response.toString());
                utils.print("MyTestError1", "" + response.statusCode);
                try {
                    JSONObject errorObj = new JSONObject(new String(response.data));
                    utils.print("ErrorInRegisterAPI", "" + errorObj.toString());

                    if (response.statusCode == 400 || response.statusCode == 405 || response.statusCode == 500) {
                        try {
                            displayMessage(errorObj.optString("error"));
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            displayMessage(getString(R.string.something_went_wrong));
                        }
                    } else if (response.statusCode == 401) {
                        try {
                            if (errorObj.optString("message").equalsIgnoreCase("invalid_token")) {
                                //Call Refresh token
                            } else {
                                displayMessage(errorObj.optString("message"));
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            displayMessage(getString(R.string.something_went_wrong));
                        }

                    } else if (response.statusCode == 422) {
                        json = trimMessage(new String(response.data));
                        if (json != "" && json != null) {
                            if (json.startsWith("The email has already been taken")) {
                                displayMessage(getString(R.string.email_exist));
                            }else{
                                displayMessage(getString(R.string.something_went_wrong));
                            }
                            //displayMessage(json);
                        } else {
                            displayMessage(getString(R.string.please_try_again));
                        }

                    } else {
                        displayMessage(getString(R.string.please_try_again));
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    displayMessage(getString(R.string.something_went_wrong));
                }
            } else {
                if (error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                    displayMessage(getString(R.string.oops_connect_your_internet));
                } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                    displayMessage(getString(R.string.oops_connect_your_internet));
                } else if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
                    registerAPI();
                }
            }
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
            return headers;
        }
    };
    AayoCabApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

Comment: How is the actual error on your app? console, screen, etc.

Comment: I have edited the question with the response in android app. @pmiranda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was problem with the end point of an API. It was solved by changing `api/provider/register` to `api/provider/sth`. It was due to the use of predefined variable in laravel.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this solution when using volley

This error 409 conflict is a client side error is caused by use of predefined variable and occurs on some networks
The solution is rename the URL address php file e.g register.php to registerAccount.php in your appconfig.

Hope it helps you